# How to find javascript stage-n features in the code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, package

For example I come into a big project with a lot of javascript code there. I'm still not aware of all the details of the code base. Is there any approach, maybe a separate tool or package which can look through all existing lines of code and show me the concrete places where `stage-0`, `stage-1` etc. features are used?